# aggregate with unwind, how to limit per document and not globally? (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I have a collection with 300 documents, each document has a array field called items (each item of the array is an object), something like this:

```
*DOCUMENT 1:*

_id: **********,
title: "test",
desc: "test desc",
items (array)
   0: (object)
     title: (string)
     tags: (array of strings)
   1: (object)
     etc.
```

and I need to retrieve items by tags, what I'm using is this query below. I have to $limit results to something like 200 or the query is too big, the problem is if the first *document* has more than 200 `items` what it returns are only items of that document, what I'd need is to limit results PER document, for instance I'd need to retrieve 5 items for each different document where tags match ($all) tags provided.

```
        const foundItems = await db.collection('store').aggregate([
            {
                $unwind: '$items'
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    'items.tags': { $all : tagsArray }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    myitem: '$items',
                    desc: 1,
                    title: 1
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: 200
            }
        ]).toArray()
```

to make it more clear and simple what I'd need in a ideal world would be something like:

```
            {
                $limit: 5,
                $per: _id,
                $totalLimit: 200
            }
```

instead of `$limit: 200` , is this achievable somehow? I didn't find any explanation about it in the official documentation.

What I tried is to add `$sort` right before `$limit` which would make sense if it had the behaviour I'm looking for put it that way and maybe not if placed AFTER the limit, but unfortunately it doesn't work that way and placed before or after the limit doesn't make any difference.

And I can't really use `$sample` since results are more than the 5%

Comment: try [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) in $project stage `myitem: { $slice: ['$items', 5] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/nM6T9XVa-XK

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $match: {
      "items.tags": {
        $all: [ "a","b" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "myitem": { "$push": "$items" },
      desc: { "$first": "$desc" },
      title: { "$first": "$title" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      desc: 1,
      title: 1,
      "myitem": { $slice: [ "$myitem",  2 ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$myitem"
  }
])
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/BESptnyUfSS

After matching the records you can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them according to id and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) them and limit them using Use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $match: {
      "items.tags": { $all: [ "a", "b" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1, myitem: "$items", desc: 1,title: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "myitem": { "$push": "$myitem" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "myitem": {
        $slice: [ "$myitem", 1 ] // limit records here per group / id
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Looks promising, how not to lose the fields "title": "test" and "desc": "test desc" in the process? I'm testing it via atlas aggregation

Comment: @m4tt add them to $group and $project pipeline here is the demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/3rTRV9cAHtW

Comment: Nice thank you, should I omit the .toArray() at the end in this case?

Comment: @m4tt yes you can do that.

Comment: The only problem with this is it returns the 5 items (if i limit to 5 where indicated)  to each document, unlike the $unwind initial purpose of creating new documents with a single item but same title/desc if part of the same document

Comment: @m4tt `$unwind` again - check this  - https://mongoplayground.net/p/nM6T9XVa-XK

Comment: Alright thanks now I can shuffle them via js